# Different header if signed-in or not

Tags: php, mysql, session, web, phpmyadmin

Is there anyway I can detect if user is login or not?

whenever I successfuly logged in, my header changes into header-signedinphp and if click the index page again, my header changes ito header.php .

I didnt put any session_destroy() on the index page.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['email_address'])){
require_once("template/header-signedin.php");
}else{  
require_once("template/header.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to add `session_start();` to the top of every PHP page in which you expect to use the session array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's probably in there, just kind of *hidden*, you know (isn't it always?) ;-) Mornin' Ralph.

Comment: It's possible @Fred-ii-. I 've lost bigger things in smaller spaces. Morning Sam ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard You stand at being 50% right on that one, well, the thang about your initial comment. Let's see what OP's got to say. Maybe it will be a "good" morning for them too, *cheers*

Comment: session_start() is triggered on the login_process. @JayBlanchard. The session start is on the header-signedin.php.

Comment: You cannot just "trigger" `session_start()` @Lemon. Is the page you show above independent of the login process?

Comment: Then you're checking a session variable in a page where the session has never been started. You *always* have to place `session_start()` at the beginning of each page you plan to use session variables in. It can be in an include, but it must be the very first thing. As an experiment add `session_start()` as the fist line of your above code.

Comment: this is the index page. it is independent, if its not the logged in, it will show the header.php not the header-signedin.

Comment: @JayBlanchard,tried it. Didn't work for me.

Comment: It's possible that you have other issues in your code @Lemon. Since we can only see the small snippet that you've provided it is hard to guess what is going on outside of the obvious. We do not know how you're including things, how you're setting your session variables or the general organization of the problem in question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard snippet is small because it is the only PHP code i started writing. the rest are HTML.

Comment: If that is all of your PHP code then you have not set a session that you can check against. Your code will always fail at this point and display `template/header.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the beginning of every PHP page in which you expect to use session data -

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['email_address'])){
    require_once("template/header-signedin.php");
}else{  
    require_once("template/header.php");
}
?>
```